# TFIDF Vectorizer within SciKit-Learn only returning 5 results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am currently working with the TFIDF Vectorizer within SciKit-Learn. The Vectorizer is supposed to apply a formula to detect the most frequent word pairs (bigrams) within a Pandas DataFrame.

The below code section however only returns the frequency analysis for five bigrams while the dataset includes thousands of bigrams for which the frequencies should be calculated.

Does anyone have a smart idea to get rid of my error that limits the number of calculations to 5 responses? I have been researching regarding a solution but have not found the right tweak yet.

The relevant code section is shown below:

```
def get_top_n_bigram_Group2(corpus, n=None):

    # settings that you use for count vectorizer will go here
    tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english', use_idf=True).fit(corpus)

    # just send in all your docs here
    tfidf_vectorizer_vectors=tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

    # get the first vector out (for the first document)
    first_vector_tfidfvectorizer=tfidf_vectorizer_vectors[0]

    # place tf-idf values in a pandas data frame
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_vector_tfidfvectorizer.T.todense(), index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["tfidf"])
    df2 = df1.sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False)

    return df2
```

And the output code looks like this:

```
for i in ['txt_pro','txt_con','txt_adviceMgmt','txt_main']:
    # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group2(df[i], 500)
    common_words.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: There is a number of issues in your question that need clarification. 1) Are you looking only for the most frequent bigrams? If yes, you may probably need the CountVectorizer, not TFIDF. Ignore this question if you really want TFIDF. 2) Why do work only with the first vector? This represents only one line of your input data. 3) Can you please state explicitly what is the output you want to have? Currently, the output of your code is the bigrams that are contained in the first document/line of the corpus and their TFIDF score.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful input. I am planning to have a scientific frequency measurement for a number of pre-defined bigrams within the given set. In this context, I have read that TFIDF was the most viable approach. Let me also take a look at the vector point you have mentioned. Ideally, the output would be a full scientific list of the bigram frequencies (while I have already counted the number of occurrences of each bigram with a separate function) and the option to only apply such frequency counts for a list of pre-selected bigrams. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I still cannot get why you need to use TFIDF. If you need to count the frequencies of predefined bigrams, you can use CountVectorizer with a predefined vocabulary. Please check my answer for a proposal.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed changes to achieve what you asked for and also taking into account your comments is as follows:

---

```
def get_top_n_bigram_Group2(corpus, n=None, my_vocabulary=None):

    # settings that you use for count vectorizer will go here
    count_vectorizer=CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), 
                                     stop_words='english', 
                                     vocabulary=my_vocabulary,
                                     max_features=n)

    # just send in all your docs here
    count_vectorizer_vectors=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

    # Create a list of (bigram, frequency) tuples sorted by their frequency
    sum_bigrams = count_vectorizer_vectors.sum(axis=0) 
    bigram_freq = [(bigram, sum_bigrams[0, idx]) for bigram, idx in count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
    
    # place bigrams and their frequencies in a pandas data frame
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(bigram_freq, columns=["bigram", "frequency"]).set_index("bigram")
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=["frequency"],ascending=False)

    return df1

# a list of predefined bigrams
my_vocabulary = ['bigram 1', 'bigram 2', 'bigram 3']
for i in ['text']:
    # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group2(df[i], 500, my_vocabulary)
    common_words.to_csv('output.csv')
```

If you do not provide the `my_vocabulary` argument in the `get_top_n_bigram_Group2()` then the `CountVectorizer` will count all bigrams without any restriction and will return only the top 500 (or whatever number you request in the second argument).

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.
Note that the [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Example_of_tf%E2%80%93idf) is not returning frequencies but rather scores (or if you prefer 'weights').

I would understand the necessity to use TFIDF if you did not have a predefined list of bigrams and you were looking for a way to score among all possible bigrams and wanted to reject those that appear in all documents and have little information power (for example the bigram "it is" appears very frequently in texts but means very little).

Comment: Many thanks for this helpful elaboration. I am using both the CountVectorizer with a specific vocabulary (which works well) and the TFIDF Vectorizer. Reason is that the scientific literature uses the formula `wi,j = tfi,j × log (N / dfi)` for the frequency determination where `wi,j` is the weight for word `i` in document `j`, `tfi,j` is the word frequency of word `i` in document `j`, `dfi` is the document frequency of term `i` in the whole corpus, and `N` is the number of documents in the corpus.

Comment: Term frequency-inverse document frequency (TF-IDF) specifically addresses the bag of word approach's weakness of an interference of common words with high word frequency. TF is the frequency of a word appearing in the document, and IDF represents the proportion of the text containing a certain word in the corpus. If you say that the `CountVectorizer` is scientifically sufficient for the analysis I will gladly take that into consideration.

Comment: I am not saying that you should use CountVectorizer instead of TfidfVectorizer. If you have a specific vocabulary, you can use it also with TfidfVectorizer. I may be able to help you more if you enhance your question to make things clearer.

Comment: That's understood. Specifically, I am working with a large DataFrame that includes positive and negative comments employees have given their firms on Glassdoor.com. In this context, I want to focus on the changing (scientific) occurrence of certain bigrams within the respective pro/con categories. Hope that helps clarifying the background...